# How to append a new item to an existing Handlebars.js template?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm new to Handlebars.js. I'm wondering how to add a new item to an existing Handlebar template. There must be a way to **render** the last item to the existing template, right?

Have a look at [my file](http://jsbin.com/epotuz/2/).

Thanks for your time!

Here is the jQuery code where I want to create the magic (for the markup: have a look at the file).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var source   = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var data =  [
  {username: "alan", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson", email: "alan@test.com"},
  {username: "allison", firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House", email: "allison@test.com"},
  {username: "ryan", firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson", email: "ryan@test.com"}
];
$("#content-placeholder").append(template(data));
$('.btn-primary').on('click',
  function(){
    var thisRow = $('.rows');
    var otherContent_1, otherContent_2, otherContent_3;
    otherContent_1 = $('#firstModal').find('input:eq(0)').val();
    otherContent_2 = $('#firstModal').find('input:eq(1)').val();
    otherContent_3 = $('#firstModal').find('input:eq(2)').val();
    var newObj = {username: otherContent_1, firstName: otherContent_2, email: otherContent_3}
    data.push(newObj);
    /*
    here is the problem how do I append/render this last-item to the template?
    */
    console.log(data.length); // I know that I've 4 items.
    $('#firstModal').modal('hide');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem:

I basically empty the whole table before I add the new item to the DOM. Then I render again the whole template because I know that my array is already updated (behind the scenes).

Thanks any way!

This will be the trick:

```
$("#content-placeholder").empty();
        $("#content-placeholder").append(template(data));
```